# Apache Ignite org.apache.ignite.internal.client.thin.ClientProtocolError "Invalid response size" and "Unexpected response ID"

Tags: java, ignite

I have a dockerized ignite instance and a dockerized java program in the same server. Ignite has a cache defined by the config xml and the java connects to it through a thin client and the cache is filled by another service. The java only does a get to ignite to get the key values.

Everything has been working as expected with this errors appearing sometimes and recreating the java docker resolved it. Today java started to show this errors every time, appearing after a few seconds of running under some load and I am not able to solve it. Already tried to empty the cache or to stop the service that fills it.

The exceptions are the following:

```
org.apache.ignite.internal.client.thin.ClientProtocolError: Unexpected response ID [4595132326738094176]
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.client.thin.TcpClientChannel.processNextResponse(TcpClientChannel.java:284)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.client.thin.TcpClientChannel.receive(TcpClientChannel.java:234)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.client.thin.TcpClientChannel.service(TcpClientChannel.java:171)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.client.thin.ReliableChannel.service(ReliableChannel.java:180)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.client.thin.ReliableChannel.affinityService(ReliableChannel.java:242)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.client.thin.TcpClientCache.cacheSingleKeyOperation(TcpClientCache.java:509)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.client.thin.TcpClientCache.get(TcpClientCache.java:111)
    at com.abc.rtpm.RtpmClient.getPrice(RtpmClient.java:63)

org.apache.ignite.internal.client.thin.ClientProtocolError: Invalid response size: -1476395008
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.client.thin.TcpClientChannel.processNextResponse(TcpClientChannel.java:275)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.client.thin.TcpClientChannel.receive(TcpClientChannel.java:234)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.client.thin.TcpClientChannel.service(TcpClientChannel.java:171)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.client.thin.ReliableChannel.service(ReliableChannel.java:180)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.client.thin.ReliableChannel.affinityService(ReliableChannel.java:242)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.client.thin.TcpClientCache.cacheSingleKeyOperation(TcpClientCache.java:509)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.client.thin.TcpClientCache.get(TcpClientCache.java:111)
    at com.abc.rtpm.RtpmClient.getPrice(RtpmClient.java:63)
```

The client is created by the following code:

```
this.cfg = new ClientConfiguration().setAddresses(clientHost + ":" + clientPort);
try {
    this.igniteClient = Ignition.startClient(this.cfg);
    this.cache = this.igniteClient.getOrCreateCache("rtpm");
}
catch (ClientException e) {
    System.err.println(e.getMessage());
}
catch (Exception e){
    System.err.format("Unexpected failure: %s\n", e);
}
```

There are several threads calling the get simultaneously.

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although in the thin client docs it says it supports multithreading it seems it cannot hold the load.

I solved this using a regular client.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are using a wrong port. You should use `10800` or the one specified by `ClientConnectorConfiguration`.

Comment: The port is properly set. As said, it works ok after a reset of the java container for a few seconds until start throwing this errors.

Comment: Then I would suggest you are using the same thin client instance from multiple threads. You should avoid that, instead opening a thin client per thread.

Comment: Ok I'll try that then. Yes the thin client is a singleton, so I'll go for a pool and let you know, thanks.

Comment: Anyway it seems odd because in their docs they say "A thin client can be called from multiple threads to increase throughput. There is no contention among parallel operations on the same thin client instance." It shouldnt be a problem to use the same client

Comment: I solved it connecting through a client, not a thin client.

Comment: Can you share a reproducer where you would get these errors upon using thin client from multiple threads? I will investigate it if the docs say so.